# insert a variable to cmd command

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I need to get a input from the user (string) and insert it in a cmd command,

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
Set LabelName = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

LabelName = InputBox("Please Enter Label to check-out:", _
  "Create File")
oShell.run "cmd /K ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008   R2\stcmd.exe"" co -p bla:bla123@123.com:7777/bla/ -is -eol on -o -rp D:\ST_test -cfgl  3.1.006"
```

the input is "LabelName" and it should insert instead of the "3.1.006"

i can't manage to insert this variable, it keeps inserting LabelName instead of the value

Comment: So what´s your question?

Comment: This is a common mistake, which is covered in the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info). VBScript doesn't expand variables inside strings. Instead you need to concatenate the variable with the two halves of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LabelName doesn't need to be a shell object, as [it's just a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Then concatenate the string onto the run command and you are done.

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
Dim LabelName

LabelName = InputBox("Please Enter Label to check-out:", _
  "Create File")
oShell.run "cmd /K ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008 R2\stcmd.exe"" co -p bla:bla123@123.com:7777/bla/ -is -eol on -o -rp D:\ST_test -cfgl  " & LabelName
```

Comment: Ok, but in this piece of code, this command doesn't run, need quotes somewhere

Comment: most likely was the triple space between 2008 and R2. Give that a try. Other than that, you get the general idea of it.

Answer (score 0):

Build your command in a more structured way - e.g:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Dim sLabel : sLabel   = "default label"
Dim oWAU   : Set oWAU = WScript.Arguments.Unnamed
If 1 <= oWAU.Count Then sLabel = oWAU(0)
Dim sCmd   : sCmd     = Join(Array( _
     "%comspec%" _
   , "/K" _
   , qq("c:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2008   R2\stcmd.exe") _
   , "co" _
   , "-p bla:bla123@123.com:7777/bla/" _
   , "-is -eol on -o -rp" _
   , qq(sLabel) _
))
WScript.Echo sCmd
```

and display the extra variable sCmd. Fixing (possible) blunders -

```
ient 2008   R2\stcm
---------^^^
```

'on second thought' additions -

```
, qq(sLabel) _
==>
, qq("D:\ST_test") _
, "-cfgl" _
, sLabel _
```

and the quoting will be much easier.

Comment: sorry, didn't understand this one, can you explain it ?

Comment: -1 answer was confusing, didnt address the original issue beyond the source code, with no explanation of the improvised execution.