# VBS WScript.Run With parameters?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a script to open up Windows movie player after a designated delay, however I cannot get windows Media Player to open up with a file passed as a parameter.

Heres what I have so far:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.run "WMplayer" & ""C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife""
```

I am getting an error on line 3 char 29 : Expected end of statement.

Can anyone help me? It'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.run "WMplayer ""C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife""",1,False
```

no need for **`&`** in between of them

OR

```
Dim objShell,myMedia
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
myMedia= chr(34) & "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife" & chr(34)
objShell.run "WMplayer "& myMedia &"",1,False
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote [correctly](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/How-To-Quote-Like-A-Pro-m81189.aspx):

```
objShell.run "wmplayer" & ""C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife""
```

==>

```
objShell.run "wmplayer" & " ""C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife"""
```

Evidence:

```
>> WScript.Echo "wmplayer" & " ""C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife"""
>>
wmplayer "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife"
>>
```

If that works from a console, it will work from your script.

For a more structured/less error prone/better scaling approach see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22481679/603855).

Answer (score 0):

If one of the command line parts is a variable, then create the whole string first, using an additional line, e.g.:

```
Dim objShell, commandlineString
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
commandlineString = WMplayer & "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife"
objShell.run commandlineString,1,False
```