# installing application with vbscript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I would like to convert this cmd command to vb script or powershell

```
c:\windows\system32\certutil.exe -f -addstore "TrustedPublisher" "Mycert.cer"
```

My problem is creating the space between "TrustedPublisher" "Mycert.cer"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In vbscript strings are enclosed in quotes. To put quotes in a string use `""` for each quote.

```
"""c:\windows\system32\wordpad"" ""c:\windows\win.ini"""
```

means the string contains

```
"c:\windows\system32\wordpad" "c:\windows\win.ini"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

1. a function to handle quoting
2. an array to store the components of the command
3. [Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscc53h0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to deal with spaces/separators

to build your commandline in a [structured way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22481679/603855). In code:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Dim aParts : aParts = Array( _
      qq("c:\windows\system32\certutil.exe") _
    , "-f" _
    , "-addstore" _
    , qq("TrustedPublisher") _
    , qq("Mycert.cer") _
)
Dim sCmd : sCmd = Join(aParts)
WScript.Echo sCmd
```

output:

```
cscript 29649158.vbs
"c:\windows\system32\certutil.exe" -f -addstore "TrustedPublisher" "Mycert.cer"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try also like this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyCmd,Ws
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
MyCmd = "c:\windows\system32\certutil.exe -f -addstore "& DblQuote("TrustedPublisher") &" "& DblQuote("Mycert.cer") &""
MsgBox MyCmd
ws.run MyCmd
'**************************************************************************
'Adding Double quotes into variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Comment: Makes more sense your code if your function adds a space after the last quote and you trim the string.