# How to execute commands with variables as path in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I can compile my visual basic project Project1.vbp into exe through this command

```
Set objWshScriptExec=objShell.Exec("cmd.exe /S /C cd ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98"" & vb6/make ""C:\Users\Ankit\Desktop\New folder (5)\Project1.vbp"" ""C:\Users\Ankit\Desktop\New folder (5)\Project1.exe""")
```

But when I take

```
p="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98"
m="C:\Users\Ankit\Desktop\New folder (5)\"
```

And try to execute this command

```
Set objWshScriptExec=objShell.Exec("cmd.exe /S /C cd "p" & vb6/make "m"Project1.vbp"" "m"Project1.exe""")
```

It results in error.

kindly provide me some solution to correct this command to compile the project to exe.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340355/launch-programs-whose-path-contains-spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate strings using `&` and also enclose your paths in `"` quotes. (Inside a string, quotes are escaped as `""`.)

```
Set d = objShell.Exec("cmd.exe /S /C cd """ & p & """ & vb6/make """ _
    & m & "Project1.vbp"" """ & m & "Project1.exe""")
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29649804/603855 if you want more structure/less noise in building commands.